# Какую схему подсветки синтаксиса использовать для заголовков HTTP-запроса?

Tags: поддержка, подсветка-синтаксиса

Наткнулся на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550886/181472), в котором подсветка синтаксиса кода слегка некорректна. Похоже, что `/*` считается комментарием к коду.

Для полноты примера использую запрос на валидацию текста вопроса, которая, кстати, была неуспешной без этой самой полноты примера.

```
POST /posts/validate-body HTTP/1.1
Host: meta.ru.stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
Content-Length: 920
Cookie: тут была печенька
X-Compress: 1
Proxy-Authorization: тут было большое число
Connection: keep-alive
```

Какую схему можно использовать в этом случае?

Comment: может вообще никакую (`lang-none`) ?

Comment: Как я понимаю, это [meta-tag:дефект]?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky скорее недонастройка.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian похоже, lang-html вполне справляется с задачей.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я увидел, что пропала подсветка комментария, но не заметил, что вместе с ней пропало и всё остальное.